# Error when I run my app on eclipse emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

I made an android app and every time i run it on Eclipse in Emulator it stops. even i have no error!It is avery simple app... but in the emulator it crashes.Ihave no ideea why is this happening. In emulator appears "the process has stopped unexpectedly" or something like this ...

Here is the LogCat:

```
05-05 09:26:58.699: D/AndroidRuntime(1222): Shutting down VM
05-05 09:26:58.749: W/dalvikvm(1222): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.create.namestrings/com.create.namestrings.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.create.namestrings.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-05 09:26:58.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     ... 11 more
05-05 09:27:51.169: E/Trace(1263): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

And here is the java file:

```
package com.create.namestrings;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    RadioButton RbtnGirl = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.radioButton1);
    RadioButton RbtnBoy = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.radioButton2);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            Random r = new Random();

            if (RbtnGirl.isChecked()){
                switch (r.nextInt(6)){
                case 0 :
                txt.setText("Esti frumoasa, "+ name);
                txt.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                 break;

                case 1 :
                txt.setText("Mi-e greata cand te vad, "+ name);
                txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                     break;

                case 2 :
                    txt.setText("Esti grasa, "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                     break;

                case 3 :
                    txt.setText("Esti puturoasa, "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                     break;

                case 4 :
                    txt.setText("Esti minunata "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                     break;

                case 5 :
                    txt.setText("Esti la moda, "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                     break;     
                }
            }else if (RbtnBoy.isChecked()){
                switch (r.nextInt(6)){
                case 0 :
                txt.setText("Esti frumos, "+ name);
                txt.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                 break;

                case 1 :
                txt.setText("Mai,"+name+"!Esti inalt ca bradu' da' prost ca gardu'!");
                txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                     break;

                case 2 :
                    txt.setText("Esti gras, "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                     break;

                case 3 :
                    txt.setText("Esti puturos, "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                     break;

                case 4 :
                    txt.setText("Esti destept "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                     break;

                case 5 :
                    txt.setText("Esti la moda, "+ name);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                     break;     
                }
            }else {
                txt.setText("Te rog, alege baiat sau fata!");
            }

            }
        });


    }

}
```

and the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.create.namestrings"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.create.namestrings.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Plese help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//Rest is the same
EditText etName;
RadioButton RbtnGirl;
RadioButton RbtnBoy;
Button btn;
TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    RbtnGirl = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.radioButton1);
    RbtnBoy = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.radioButton2);
    btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
    //Rest is the same
```

Instead of your code.

Your were getting a `NullPointerException` when using `btn` in `onCreate()`. This is because `findViewById()` looks for the View in the currently inflated layout, which does not exist until `setContentView()` has been called. As you were initializing your Views outside of a method, they all get a null value because `onCreate()`, which calls `setContentView()`, hasn't been called yet.

Answer (score 0):

After setting layout content,you find ids

```
   private EditText etName;
   private RadioButton RbtnGirl;
   private RadioButton RbtnBoy;
   private Button btn;
   private TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    RbtnGirl = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.radioButton1);
    RbtnBoy = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.radioButton2);
    btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
    ......
```

You were finding the id before setting the view to the layout. Hence you were getting NullPointerException.

I updated my answer you would have to make text view final if do as below since you would be using textview on button click. This is unnecessary so declare the variables as class variables.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Textview txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
```